# Is there a way to limit the amount of while loops or input loops in Python?

Tags: python

I was just wondering if there is a way to limit the amount of times a user can input something on a while loop. This is simply a guess a number 1-100 game. I have the found variable = False.

```
while not found:
    user_guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
    if user_guess == random_number:
        print("you got it!")
        found = True
    elif user_guess > random_number:
        print("Guess lower")
    else:
        print("guess higher")
```

I wanted to see if i could make this code seem more like a game by limiting the amount a user can guess for the input. Ive had some ideas i just cannot wrap my head around it. do i have set a variable value for the input to set the amount of times it can run? Im new to programming so i am struggling a bit.

Comment: You need a counter; that you add 1 to in the loop; or use a `for` loop with `range `instead of `while` loop

Comment: You can keep a counter of `guesses`, e.g. `guesses = 0`. Then, at the end of your while_loop, `guesses += 1`. Your condition can be `while guesses < 3` for example, to limit it to 3 guesses. And then, instead of keeping track of `found`, just `break` out when `user_guess == random_number`. Or use a for-loop, and break-out accordingly.

Answer (score 6):

```
count = 0
max_guesses_allowed = pick your max here

while not found or count < max_guesses_allowed:
    user_guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
    if user_guess == random_number:
        print("you got it!")
        found = True
    elif user_guess > random_number:
        count += 1
        print("Guess lower")

    else:
        count += 1
        print("guess higher")
```

Comment: should it be and instead of or?

Comment: @alexmogavero, it needs to stop the loop if the player guesses the answer OR if the player reached the max amount of guesses.

Answer (score 1):

The standard way would be to count the number of loops, and then exit if they exceed the maximum.

```
max_allowed = 10
attempt = 0

while not found:
    attempt += 1
    user_guess = int(input("Your guess: "))
    if user_guess == random_number:
        print("you got it!")
        found = True
    elif attempt == max_allowed:
        print("You've reached the maximum number of guesses.")
        break
    elif user_guess > random_number:
        print("Guess lower")
    else:
        print("guess higher")
```

Comment: If you guess correctly the last time it will tell you you got it and you've reached the maximum number of guesses... it's unclear if that is intended behavior.

Comment: If they're allowed 10 attempts, and they guess it on the 10th attempt, it will tell them that they found it. That's the behaviour that I would expect.

Comment: @TemporalWolf No, the other cases won't be hit if the `if` case was entered.  That's the entire purpose of an if/elif/else construction.