# Setting a global cap for while loops

Tags: python, loops, while-loop

I have a lot of while loops in my program. Each one breaks only if a certain condition is met. However the nature of the program is such that the condition may never be met, which would run the loop infinitely.

Practically, I could just add a counter to each while loop and terminate them if the number of iterations exceed. Is there a better way to handle this in python, say, set a cap for all loops in the program?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to limit the amount of while loops or input loops in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42169892/is-there-a-way-to-limit-the-amount-of-while-loops-or-input-loops-in-python)

Comment: @pippo1980 they use a counter which is exactly what I wish to have a workaround for

Comment: I would expect to get all posdible solution there as the question is:  Is there a way to limit the amount of while loops or input loops in Python?

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'global limit'.

You can use decorators to limit a while loop by count or by time.

Here is a time out decorator:

```
import time

def time_out(timeout=1.0):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            timeout_start = time.monotonic()
            while time.monotonic() < timeout_start + timeout:
                function(*args, **kwargs)
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

Or a count out decorator:

```
def cnt_out(limit=10):
    def decorator(function):
        def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
            cnt=0
            while cnt < limit:
                function(*args, **kwargs)
                cnt+=1
        return wrapper
    return decorator
```

You would use like so:

```
@time_out(timeout=0.0001)
def a_function(args):
    print(f'hello{time.time()}')

# later

a_function('whatever_args')
```

Prints:

```
hello1702913605.3413372
hello1702913605.341354
hello1702913605.341357
... # lots of lines...
hello1702913605.341433
hello1702913605.341435
```

Or by count:

```
@cnt_out(limit=3)    
def b_function(args):
    print(f'hello from {args}')

# later...

b_function('b_func')
```

Prints:

```
hello from b_func
hello from b_func
hello from b_func
```

So just put the body of the `while` loop inside a decorator function.

You can also use the return of the decorated function as a termination for the `while` loop inside the wrapper.

Comment: cool @dwag , got it too here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35490555/python-timeout-decorator

Answer (score 0):

The most simple solution would be to define a boolean (or event) to use as the while loop condition instead of `True`. Inverting the boolean will stop the loop.

```
should_run = True

while should_run:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

Stealing from here: [How would I stop a while loop after n amount of time?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13293269/how-would-i-stop-a-while-loop-after-n-amount-of-time)

It's not a global cap for loops, but nevertheless I think could be a solution:

```
import time


timeout = time.time() + 10   #  seconds from now

cnt = 0
while True:
    test = 0
    if test == 5 or time.time() > timeout:
        break
    test = test - 1

    cnt += 1
    
    print(cnt)
    

print(cnt, timeout)
```

Comment: Well, the timeout will work but that `test == 5` will never happen...

Comment: question is .. However the nature of the program is such that the condition may never be met, which would run the loop infinitely....